# How to map a RESTful API to an URL in BackboneJS model and collections?

Tags: javascript, url, backbone.js, collections, model

I have the following RESTful API:

`GET /club/1.0/club.json?sport=FO&country=ES`

This service gives a list of clubs by sport and country (ex: Football in Spain)

`GET /club/1.0/club.json?id=xxxx`

This service gives the details of a club

In Backbone.js, I try the following URLs for a Collection::

**`http://localhost:3000/club/1.0/club.json`**,

Questions:

1. How can I deal with the versioning ?
2. How can I specified the required parameters that are **sport** and **country** ?

For the model I use this urlRoot :

**`http://localhost:3000/club/1.0/club.json`**,

I think this one is easy because the save method will add **/:id** to the urlRoot that will work with my ExpressJS server.

Thank you for the answer(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set that using Backbone sync in your collections/models. Example:

Collection:

```
var ClubCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: ClubModel,
  sync: function(method, collection, options){ 
    options = _.extend({}, options, {url: 'club/1.0/club.json');
    return $.ajax(options);
  }
});
```

Model

```
var ClubModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  sync: function(method, model, options){ 
    options = _.extend({}, options, {url: 'club/1.0/club.json');
    switch (method) {
      case 'read':
   options.data = _.extend({}, options.data, {
        id: model.id
       });
  break;
  // case 'delete':
  // break;
  // case 'update':
  // break;
  // case 'create':
  // break;
   }
   return $.ajax(options);
  }
});
```

Then make the request using `yourCollection.fetch({data:{sport:'FO',country:'ES'}})`. And for your model can be `myModel.set('id', 1).fetch()`.

UPDATE: Oh, and for the versioning, you can use a variable instead of the number directly.

Answer (score 1):

*How can I deal with the versioning ?*

If you have, let's say, a global variable holding the version's value (or some other scope variable, this doesn't change the point), you can either do something like `urlRoot: '/club/' + VERSION + '/club.json'` in your class declaration, or declare `urlRoot` as a function (has no particular advantage here) `urlRoot: function() {return '/club/' + VERSION + '/club.json';}`.

*How can I specified the required parameters that are sport and country ?*

An easy way would be to add them in the `data` option of your `fetch` call (you can pass any jQuery `ajax` method's option to your Backbone AJAX calls): `myModel.fetch({data: {sport: 'FO', country: 'ES'}});`.

Comment: I like this. One small note to the api implementer: You should also pass the version as a data option to the API ?version=xxx will be more robust in the long run.